# equal jump between numbers in two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to compare two arrays. One of them is a subset of the other one. I want my function to return the minimum and equal gap between the numbers of the first subset array in the other array.

For example if I have

```
arr1 = 2,1,4,2,8,3
sub= 1,2,3
```

I want my function to return 1 because the mimimum gap between all this numbers are 1.

```
arr1 = 2,1,5,2,1,2,3
sub= 1,2,3
```

I want my function to return 0 because the mimimum gap between 1,2,3 in arr1 is 0

Here is the code I am trying to do: My code always return  0 can you help me understand why, and how can I solve this.

```
     int gap(int* arr, int* sub, int sizeArr, int sizeSub)
{
    int index = 0; int gap = 0; bool flag = true;
    int i = -1;
    for (int jump = 1; jump < sizeArr / sizeSub; jump++)
    {
        index = 0;
        for (i = i +1; i < sizeArr; i++)
        {
            if (sub[index] == arr[i])
            {
                for (int j = i + jump, index = 1; j < sizeArr; j = j + jump, index++)
                {
                    if (arr[j] != sub[index]) { flag = false; break; }
                    else if (arr[j] == sub[index] && index == sizeSub) { flag = true; break; }
                }
            }
            if (!flag) { break; }
            else { gap = jump; break; }
        }
    }
    return gap;
}
```

Comment: Since you are trying to find the minimum jump, I would write code something like this `int gap(int* arr1, int* sub, int sizearr1, int sizesub) { for (int jump = 1; jump <= sizearr1/sizesub; ++jump) ...` I.e. start looking for a jump of size one, if you don't find it then look for a jump of size two etc. Maybe something more complicated would be more efficient, but that's where I would start.

Comment: I understand what you want I do. But I don't have idea how to implement this with two arrays. And why your loop until sizearr1/sizesub

Comment: So, the gap is the longest sequence of numbers that are not part of the second array? I'd say that almost matches, but from the two examples it's difficult to tell. BTW: Is your second array a set? In that case elements are unique and their order doesn't matter. In any case, concerning your actual question, use a debugger to step through the code to find out where exactly it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You initially took gap equally `0` but i think more suit to not store `gap`
and start iterate `jump` from `0`. And return jump immediately after you found that it is suit.

Also i think that store index in such manner as you it is bad idea, because you code return wrong answer on

```cpp
int a[] = { 2,1,4,4,2,8,5,3 };
int s[] = { 1,2,3 };
```

I think you should declare variable as soon as possible, otherwise there will be undesirable side effects.

So you code can be rewritten as

```cpp
int gap(int *arr, int *sub, int sizeArr, int sizeSub)
{
    for (int jump = 0; 1 + (jump + 1) * (sizeSub - 1) <= sizeArr; jump++) {
        for (int start_index = 0; start_index + (jump + 1) * (sizeSub - 1) < sizeArr; start_index++) {
            bool flag = true;
            for (int index = 0; index < sizeSub; ++index) {
                if (arr[start_index + index * (jump + 1)] != sub[index]) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                return jump;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1; //or some value that indicate that there is no answer
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. Can you explain what are your logical behind the code and what your nested loop are doing, and what it is mean 1 + (jump + 1) * (sizeSub - 1) <= sizeArr

Comment: Firstly I iterate over jump
When I try to find position where subArray appear in Array taking into account gaps
so in
```int a[] = { 2,8,1,4,2,5,3 };
int s[] = { 1,2,3 };```
start position when `jump=1` is 2.

And third loop check that subset really appear in this position.
```1 + (jump + 1) * (sizeSub - 1) <= sizeArr```
checks that at least theoretically we can place our subArray in Array with `gap=jump`